# Feature I want to add to my Amazon Connect scheduling app

Tags: amazon-connect

So we wrote a React app that lets call center admins create holidays, special events, meetings and emergency conditions for Amazon Connect. In version 2.0 I would like to be able to allow admins to use an uploaded pre-recorded prompt and select that for an announcement from my React app. I have searched the API and it has no endpoint for listing or creating prompt. Does anyone else know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API for Prompt Management. Right now, you would have to manually reference the ARN value of the Prompt to dynamically play it via a lambda within a contact flow. Just looked into this myself for a similar feature, and confirmed w/ AWS team.

Comment: Can confirm that AWS said this is the case - we did exactly what you suggest with the ARN value of the prompt.

Comment: Hopefully they will add this feature soon!